# SQL query to convert columns into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as shown below.My question is:How can I convert columns into rows? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

```
   sip_RECno  user1     user2    user3     user4       

   1          ram       ravi     sam       raj
```

i need op like below

```
 user
 ram
 ravi
 sam
 raj
```

how to do it? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: possibility of "converting columns into rows" being duplicate of "converting rows into columns" is quite little though.

Comment: really? PIVOT vs. UNPIVOT - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(sip_RECno INT,user1 VARCHAR(10),user2 VARCHAR(10)
,user3 VARCHAR(10),user4 VARCHAR(10))      

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,'ram','ravi','sam','raj')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT user1 ,user2 ,user3 , user4 FROM @TABLE) T
  UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (user1 ,user2 ,user3 , user4))P
  )
 SELECT Value AS Users
 FROM CTE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╗
║ Users ║
╠═══════╣
║ ram   ║
║ ravi  ║
║ sam   ║
║ raj   ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: how to do for dynamic columns ?

Comment: @Happy it will be another long answer to explain this have a look here scroll down to the middle of this page to see how dynamicaly pivot/unpivot data http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/516896/Calculate-aggregates-for-dynamic-columns-using-UNP

Answer (score 5):

You can simply `UNPIVOT()`

```
select [user] from table_name unpivot 
      (
       [user]
       for [userid] in ([user1], [user2], [user3], [user4]) 
      )unpvt
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad421/1)

Comment: how to do for dynamic columns ?

Comment: by using Dynamic SQL and ` FOR XML PATH`